# Multiple routers on the same network over coax

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am attempting to set up a home network.  As the only existing infrastructure in the house is coax, I was informed that I would be able to hook up a cable modem (modem router combo) to existing coax connections in the house, setting all 3 (1 in the basement, 1 on the 1st floor and 1 on the 2nd floor) up with the same SSID and password so my devices would switch to the strongest signal when the other signal dropped.

*Note: I really don't want to dig into the walls and run cabling throughout the house.*

I went out and purchased 3 - ARRIS SURFboard SBG6782-AC DOCSIS 3.0 Cable Modem and AC1750 Wi-Fi Routers as was recommended to me.

I verified with my cable company (Comcast / Xfinity) that I could add all 3 to my account and it would split my bandwidth, but should increase my coverage.

My question is this - Before I go ahead and do this whole set-up, was i given bad advice or should this work?

Comment: I'd prefer powerline networking rather than coax. But good luck!

Comment: MOCA might be an option internally, but I've not tried it personally.Its a standard that uses co-ax cabling for local lan

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you already bought the equipment, why not try it out and let us know how it goes?

One problem you will probably run into is that the seperate floors won't be able to connect to one another (ie. if your NAS is in the basement, you wouldn't be able to access it on the attic), since they will be seperate networks, only connected over the internet. You could create VPN tunnels between the routers and set up internal routing that way, but depending on how your ISP does bandwidth limiting, you might end up with low bandwidth connections between floors (at least, a lot slower than gigabit ethernet).

Also, unless proper handovers are used, most WiFi devices will only disconnect when the signal goes under a critical value and then start searching for other access points. Since all three WiFi AP's are connected to different networks, it'd be a challenge to set up proper WiFi handovers between them. I know Cisco Aironet can do this, but it's prohibitively expensive for home use. So you'll probably experience slow connections unless you actively switch WiFi networks.

You don't want to dig into the walls and run cabling, but why not replace the existing coax for ethernet cables? You can use the same cable ducts and get a proper connection. I replaced telephone wire with ethernet on several occasions and that worked brilliantly. Just tie the ethernet to the end of the cable and pull it through. Alternatively, there is always ethernet over power (Powerline) equipment, although the proper ethernet option is *much* better.

Comment: I would also add collision domain as a resulting problem because of the multiple routers acting as modems.

Comment: Since it's a SOHO setup, I don't think the collision domain would be the problem. He'd only have max. 15 devices connected.

Comment: Not necessarily, I've got 20+ devices connected over wireless + wired; and running over Coax, if at all possible, would cause a collision domain as it is unmanaged.

Answer (score 2):

**Before you begin reading my answer, please note that my understanding is that you wish to use these routers as independent modems broadcasting on the same SSID with the same WEP/WPA(2) key, and same settings.**

Personally, I would take it for a test run and see how it performs (seeing that you already dropped a good $500 into the equipment); however I would also say this is bad advice for many reasons. Many people (*without* splitting their bandwidth) use wireless or wired **range extenders** or **repeaters**. The effect of running 3 routers on the same coaxial source can *monumentally* impact your bandwidth in a negative way (it can also result in a very nasty and chaotic network, referred to as a [collision domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_domain), where the system can become stressed if you are not careful). Another big danger is cluttering of the frequency bands. If you intend to run the routers on the same 'channel', they will see each-other's broadcasts as noise (I hope I don't have to explain why this is a problem.) Else, your three routers clutter up the 1, 6, and 11 channels on the 2.4GHz band; these are the three most commonly endorsed channels, and therefore, the most cluttered *already*. Also, taking from [@mtak's](https://superuser.com/users/283161/mtak) answer, you'll run into a problem with a divided network, meaning that your NAS per se may not be accessible from your attic or 2nd floor.

---

If you're going to do anything in regards to coverage, you should see if the routers support an "AP" or "Access Point" mode in lieu of a routing mode. The cable modem should work *in conjunction* with the access points to provide better coverage while not splitting your bandwidth. I *highly* recommend you invest in some inexpensive [**MoCA adapters**](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=-1&IsNodeId=1&Description=moca%20adapter&bop=And&Order=PRICE&PageSize=36), I bet they would be worth your while. This way you might be able to wire your house in a way that you can directly connect your personal computers to the wired network. In the future, try to get a second opinion before you delve into something as surprisingly difficult as this.

---

If you're too pained by the *$500* you just blew on Wi-Fi equipment to deal with unsightly wires in your house, or spend a day in your attic or crawlspace routing cables, you should stick to a little bit of light reading or homework. For now, I would search your two routers' settings for an access point mode. ***Just don't get your hopes up because even though they may have the setting, it can sometimes be locked down to wiring the routers together.*** Many routers have this ability built in, and it would be safe to assume so. Good luck in your endeavors, and try to keep things as simple as possible!

---

Tl;dr

Try not to use them as routers, but instead as repeaters, or access points. By using them as routers, you make a divided network and disable access to your wireless printer in the den if you're in the basement, working on your NAS (you should get one if you don't already!)

Answer (score 0):

Cable modems don't talk to each other, they only talk to (expensive) head-end equipment (CMTS). DOCSIS requires a hybrid coax/fiber infrastructure.

See this [question, comments, and answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/33197/8499) on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This does not directly answer the question, nor does it offer a possible solution to the problem.

Comment: @varfirstName, I believe it does. The modems cannot talk to each other. There will be three separate networks which cannot communicate, and the coax cannot be used as a cable replacement.

Comment: I disagree. You don't offer a true solution, and you also leave OP to assume what you mean. You leave him confused between yourself and your ISP, and you segue into another SE site to a question that has no marked solution.

Comment: @varfirstName, the question doesn't ask for a solution, it asks, "_should this work?_" Providing an unasked for solution would be a non-sequitur.

Comment: Just to clarify, did you mean unanswered?

Comment: @varfirstName, I don't know what you mean. The question did not ask for a solution, so providing a solution is unasked for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44654/discussion-between-var-firstname-and-ron-maupin).